# Double Fourier series and applications

Tags: fourier-series

I would like to know following opinion :

We know that by using  Fourier expansion of $f(x)=|x|$ over $0<x<\pi$ one can prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$ and thus $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Furthermore, by using Fourier expansion of $f(x)=|\cos zx|$ over $-\pi<x<\pi$ , $z\not\in\mathbb{Z}$  and Bernoulli numbers, one can generalize $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2k}}=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(2\pi)^{2k}B_{2k}}{2(2k)!}$$  for all positive integers $k$. Here $B_n$ is the $n$-th Bernoulli number.

As you see these are very useful results, show the cool beauty in mathematics. Now I want know that  are there any these kind of nice results which can be obtained by Double Fourier Series?? Is there any mathematician who attacked to Riemann hypothesis from this approach??

Comment: What do you mean by "Double Fourier Series"? Sum of two Fourier series? Product of two Fourier series? Nested sum of an infinite number of Fourier series? There are lots of results that can be obtained from the last one.

Comment: @Steven Clark Sir , Fourier Series of $f(x,y)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]\times [-\pi,\pi]$